# Motion sensing home security cameras that work with Windows 10 (or standalone) and have both iOS and Android apps

Tags: ip-camera, video-camera, home-security

I have several brands of home security cameras (WiLife, Dlink, Logitech, TrendNet), but they all have issues with Windows 8 and later.  What home security cameras exist that work entirely without a computer or with the latest version of Windows?

I'm not interested in cameras that require new wiring. I'm looking for cameras that use either WiFi or Powerline adapters.

Resolution isn't a big concern, though HD would be nice. Price is more of a factor, as I'd like to stay under $50/each and no monthly fees.

Apps to view the cameras are a must, the ability to remotely view past motion would be awesome.

These would be primarily indoor daytime cameras without optical pan/tilt/zoom (mainly because I don't foresee any possibility of those features for $50 or less in the near future).  Viewing angle is also not a concern for $50 cameras.

Audio would also be nice, but not required (I point most of them outside, so audio doesn't really work anyway).

Comment: What other specs are you looking for? It's difficult to recommend IP cameras based on just a compatible OS and connectivity.

Comment: As Adam says, it would be nice to have more requirements. What kind of focal length are you looking for? How wide should the field of vision be?

Comment: More requirements to consider that could narrow your question: Do you want cameras that can pan? Tilt? Zoom? All three? Should they have a microphone as well? Weatherproof or indoor?

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://netatmo.com
I love their "weather" station (I have 5 independent "weather" stations with a total of 13 additional add-on indoor modules - never even the smallest hiccup with any of them).

I also have their "Presence" external camera at one site. It is mains powered & WiFi (only 2.4GHz) and when it works, it works wonderfully (HD, night IR, car/person/animal "event" detection (with auto-floodlight by event category if you wish, with alerts to your mobile by event category if you wish), no monthly fees, iOS, macOS, Android apps (probably Win too but I don't use it). Whack in a big SD card and you're fine...

BUT

...no way is it $50

...it is not hiccup free. I have had to invoke intervention from their support folk twice (f/w upgrade issues) but they managed to get everything working remotely (site is 3 hour round trip away, so I can't get involved with hiccups)

They also do internal cams that are closer to your $50 - I have never used them so cannot comment. Chris

Don't worry about the "weather" quote marks: I use their stuff for monitoring internal and external temperatures, not trying to predict weather (and the camera for monitoring snowfall in the mountains)